# Keeping database foreign keys consistent

Tags: python, django, database, schema, database-normalization

I am trying to write a django app with a PostgreSQL database. My problem can be reduced to the following minimal example:

Organization

- has 0 ... N workers

Worker

- belongs to an organization

Task

- belongs to an organization
- is assigned to no-one, or assigned to one worker within the same organization

I am unsure of how to design the database in a way that prevents inconsistent state - since both Worker and Task need to have a foreign key pointing to the Organization they belong to, it is possible to end up with an inconsistent state where a worker from organization A is assigned a task from organization B.

The only solution I could think of was verifying the constraint in the save method:

```
class Organization(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class Worker(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Task(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    assigned_to = models.ForeignKey(Worker, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.assigned_to and self.assigned_to.organization != self.organization:
            raise ValidationError('Task and Worker belong in different Organizations.')
        return super(Task, self).save(*args, **kwargs
```

Is it possible to create a better solution which still prevents inconsistent state? My own solution doesn't seem like a good one from a database design point of view.

Comment: One factor to consider is what happens if a worker changes organizations. Is that allowed? Do their tasks switch organizations too, or do they become unassigned? And so on. That might inform your design.

Comment: You want a task FK (worker, org) to worker. A FK says subrows must appear elsewhere a PKs. We need to identify all the restrictions that our database tables have & declare what we can as constraints & enforce others via triggers. This is a faq, that you might find if you googled many clear concise specific phrasings of your question/problem/goal. with & without your particular strings/names. PS Re downvoter presumably they think it is either unclear and/or not useful (maybe because it's a faq or there's no [mcve])--see the downvote arrow mouseover text.

Comment: You'd need to implement a `check`. I got it from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39884447/1637351

Comment: To add to @philipxy answer, I have found this [post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/138437) which also suggests a composite foreign key. To that end I have found this django module: [django-composite-foreignkey](https://pypi.org/project/django-composite-foreignkey/)